# shardCollection command not working in mongosh

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am trying to shard my collection using mongosh, but its given error "no such command 'shardCollection' Are you connected to mongoose ? ".
I am searched that error on google but i didnt find anything about this error.

```
 sh.shardCollection("my-db.users",{"userId":1})
```

I am using the above code with mongo shell but it gives an error. I tried on the shell that came with Mongodb Compass, but I get the same error.

Comment: What version of MongoDB and mongosh?

Comment: Do you run local MongoDB or Atlas? Did you deploy a sharded cluster?

Comment: mongosh : 1.10.3, mongoDB: 5.3, im working with localhost.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a sharded cluster, you need a Config Server Replica Set (CSRS), at least one mongos node, and at least one shard.  See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/sharding/

When running sharding commands like "shardCollection" you will need to connect to a mongos node, not one of the mongod nodes.

Comment: What is it mean ?

Comment: `sh.shardCollection` is a sharding command.  You can't run sharding commands on a mongod, you have to run them on a mongos.

Comment: How i can run mongos ?

Comment: The mongos binary comes with the mongodb server package.  See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongos/